# Intuition for p norm

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry

Beyond the mathematical formula, I can't get the intuition behind norms other than norm 1 or norm 2. It is pretty intuitive that the "Manhattan norm" is the distance if you can move on only one dimension at a time, and that the norm 2 is the way you calculate distance for most concrete things in life, you I can't represent myself what would mean, for example, a norm 3.

Does anyone have an example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Imagine you want to compare or combine volumes or masses of liquid, quantities represented as spherical balloons measured by their radius. The combination is the sum of the volumes, and this total volume is equivalent to a sphere or radius $r_{tot}=(\sum r_i^3)^{1/3}$.
If now you have boxes which each contains exactly a red, a green and a blue balloon of random radius, it can be represented by the triplet of radius. Then you can compare and sort the boxes using this "equivalent radius" norm.

Ok this example might look artificial, but I guess it might apply for instance to set of stars (knowing that their total volume come from the previous dust cloud in that region).

Comment: I see, thank you. So basically a "higher norm" means that the "distance" you try to measure will be much more affected by extreme values. In statistics I suppose OLS would be norm 2, and it would be norm 4 if you were taking the errors to the power of 4 instead of 2.